# django-leaflet + leaflet-rastercoord (macOS 10.13.6 + homebrew)

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, django-leaflet

I am working on a postgres based django project to create floor plans. I have experience in python3 but js is new to me. I need this to be running in very basic functionality in the next 6 days. So yes: My sweat turned acid.

The goal is pretty damn simple: Floor plan with updating overlays (e.g. blue rectangle marks free storage etc).

What I need:

- Floor plan as base-map
- rectangular (updating) overlays
- markers

Django-leaflet works fine, but rastercoord is killing me. I simply tried to implement the demo code into my template html and it seems like it just silently fails to execute. Django-leaflet itself works like a charm, markers are displayed and so on.

I modified the original example code to use my tiled milkyway image from wikipedia, which works just fine.

```js
/*
 * @copyright 2015 commenthol
 * @license MIT
 */

/* global L */

;(function (window) {
    function init (mapid) {
    var minZoom = 0
    var maxZoom = 5
    var img = [
      6000, // original width of image `karta.jpg`
      3000  // original height of image
    ]

    // create the map
    var map = L.map(mapid, {
      minZoom: minZoom,
      maxZoom: maxZoom
    })

    // assign map and image dimensions
    var rc = new L.RasterCoords(map, img)

    // set the view on a marker ...
    map.setView(rc.unproject([1, 1447]), 4)


    // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
    L.tileLayer('./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      noWrap: true,
      attribution: 'VOID'
    }).addTo(map)
  }
  init('map')
}(window))
```

But implemented in django nothing happens. The map is displayed with default settings.
The template HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
{% load leaflet_tags %}
  <head>
    <meta name=Locator charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons/css/tachyons.min.css">
    <title>EUT Locator</title>
    {% leaflet_js plugins="ALL" %}
    {% leaflet_css plugins="ALL" %}
  </head>
  <style>
  * {
    font-family: avenir;
    margin: 1%;
  }
  .leaflet-container {  /* all maps */
    width:  600px;
    height: 600px;
}

  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>This is what you get</h1>
    <p>Not much, really</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function map_init_raster (mapid, options) {
            var minZoom = 0
            var maxZoom = 5
            var img = [
              6000, // original width of image `karta.jpg`
              3000  // original height of image
            ]

            // create the map
            var map = L.map(mapid, {
              minZoom: minZoom,
              maxZoom: maxZoom
            })

            // assign map and image dimensions
            var rc = new L.rastercoords(map, img)

            // set the view on a marker ...
            map.setView(rc.unproject([1, 1447]), 4)


            // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
            L.tileLayer('./milkyway/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              noWrap: true,
              attribution: 'VOID'
            }).addTo(map)
          }
          init('map')
          }
    </script>

    {% leaflet_map "yourmap" callback="window.map_init_raster" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The interesting part of the settings.py:

```html
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
'SRID' : 3857,
'DEFAULT_CENTER': (0, 0),
'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 1,
'MIN_ZOOM': 0,
'MAX_ZOOM': 5,
'RESET_VIEW': False,
'PLUGINS': {
    'rastercoords': {
        'css': '',
        'js': 'leaflet-rastercoords/rastercoords.js',
        'auto-include': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Cheers with tears
Hobel

Comment: Double check the parameters you're passing to the `L.map(...)` factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback take the map as a parameter and not the id of a map. The map is already created. Try this out:

```js
function map_init_raster (map, options) {
    var img = [
      6000, // original width of image `karta.jpg`
      3000  // original height of image
    ];

    // assign map and image dimensions
    var rc = new L.rastercoords(map, img);

    // set the view on a marker ...
    map.setView(rc.unproject([1, 1447]), 4);


    // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
    L.tileLayer('./milkyway/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      noWrap: true,
      attribution: 'VOID'
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

I don't know rastercoords so I can't help you on that.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work. But at least it lead me to the part causing the script not to execute.

```var rc = new L.rastercoords(map, img);```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was all about faulty STATIC configuration in settings.py

I altered the settings.py like this (Thanks to: https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-static-files-handling/)

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dump'),
```

And in the HTML template it works with this code

```
        function map_init_raster (map) {
        var img = [6000, 3000];

        // assign map and image dimensions
        var rc = new L.RasterCoords(map, img);


        map.setView(rc.unproject([1000, 1000]), 3)

        // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
        L.tileLayer('/static/mw/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          noWrap: true,
          attribution: 'VOID'
        }).addTo(map);
        }
```

Previously it failed because of a typo regarding the case-sensitivity (doesnt work:'L.rastercoords' works: L.RasterCoords)

Appears that I didn't knew what RasterCoords is actually doing. It works.